# linux process exiting takes too long

Tags: linux, memory, process, linux-kernel

Here is my problem, when I send `kill` command to my process, no matter `kill -9` or `kill -TERM`, my process steps into zombie(defunct) stats which needs the father process to call `waitpid` to catch the exit status. But it takes about 5-7 seconds which is too long.

```
$ ps -ef | grep store
web_ser+  2793     1 30 May24 ?        1-12:13:45 [my_test] <defunct>
web_ser+ 45462 33954  0 20:22 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto store
```

However, when I use `pstack` to print the father process, its still block in `waitpid`:

```
$ pstack 46046
#0  0x00007ffa2d078dbc in waitpid () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000000004012c3 in main ()
```

I don't known why it cost so many time to exit, this process uses about 70G memory, maybe it is because of the memory reclaim, but I've no idea to find the problem, could anyone give some ideas?

Comment: *Every* process becomes a zombie when it terminates, no matter how it terminates.  The only thing unusual in what you describe is that the process remains a zombie for several seconds despite its parent process being blocked in a `waitpid()` call that eventually does collect it.

Comment: We don't have enough information to give a definitive answer, and I'm not sure there's a way for you to give us such.  The large memory usage might well be related, however.  My first guess would be that the parent is mostly swapped out (because the child needed so much memory), and it takes time to swap it back in.  That would be especially plausible if the parent also has a large memory footprint.  The solution in that case would be adding more RAM and / or a faster swap device, or to reduce the memory requirements of both processes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for your reply, the parent process is just a hypervisor that is simply run `waitpd`. The total memory is not run out, and the kernel SWAP option is turned off. As I go through [Expedited memory reclaim from killed processes](https://lwn.net/Articles/785709/), maybe there is something else that make my process hung up.

Comment: even if I kill parent process first to let my process token over by init process, this problem still can not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to check if there are any standing NFS/shared-folder connection that need to be terminated on both ends.

In more general, check for any network dependencies that need to be cleared.

Also, check for any special device drivers used by the application (GPU/Graphic Card/USB device/BlueTooth device/Wifi adapter/ printer...) . Some low quality device drivers need time to disengage.